# If everybody uses the 5GHz WiFi band, won't it have the same issues as the 2.4GHz band?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, bandwidth, wifi-configuration

Recently, I've had many issues with my home WiFi connection. I purchased a WiFi extender that works only in the 2.4GHz frequency, only to realize that the 2.4GHz band in my house is extremely slow when compared to the 5GHz band of the same router (10 times slower or more). I hadn't notice before because I was using my computer in another room where I was closer to the router and I could connect directly to its 5GHz network. By reading online, I found out that everybody was suggesting to drop the 2.4GHz network and use the 5GHz network instead. So I returned the extender and bought one compatible with the 5GHz band.

However, I was wondering: if everybody does the same, i.e. they stop using the 2.4GHz network and use the 5GHz one instead, won't this make the 5GHz network congested as well and slower? I know that some devices, e.g. baby monitors, printers, are using the 2.4GHz band only. But what if these devices will be designed to use the 5GHz too? Won't this cause the same issues on the 5GHz band?

Comment: I'lll et someone with hard figures provide the actual answer, but the 5GHz band will take longer to fill to capacity. It can handle more data, faster, across more channels. So.. yes, but not right away. 2.4 is already over-full, & includes bluetooth & TV remotes etc which are not technically "WiFi"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer to this is yes, with time it will be just as bad as 2.4Ghz.

The 5Ghz band was underutilized in most areas here for the better part of a decade. When wireless-a was first released the channels were 20Mhz wide.

This allowed for 9 non-overlapping channels in the 5.8Ghz band (uni1). This was quite a bit more than the three non-overlapping channels offered for 2.4 GHz devices using 20Mhz wide channels. (3x more)

There were more channels opened up later called DFS channels that had the requirement to listen for radar blips, passing satellites, ect so that if it was in range of such devices it would automatically change the channel the AP was transmitting on. (Dynamic Frequency Selection)

This brought the total available channels to 25 non-overlapping 20Mhz channels in the 5.8 band.

Here is the problem, 802.11ac... This allows you to use wider channels (20, 40, 80 up to 160mhz wide) for better bandwidth / throughput, but sacrifices pretty much the whole original spectrum to do so.

So, as newer routers have been released, they now support 80Mhz & 160Mhz wide channels.
This presents a new problem of congestion for this band.

- **20 MHz**: channels 36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56, 60, 64, 100, 104, 108, 112, 116,120, 124, 128, 132, 136, 140, 144, 149, 153, 161, 165, 169 are all available when using 20Mhz wide channels.
- **40 MHz**: channels 38, 46, 54, 62, 102, 110, 118, 126, 134, 142, 151, 159 are available.
- **80 MHz**: channels 42, 58, 106, 122, 138, 155 are available.
- **160 MHz** channels 50 & 114 are available.

Newer wireless-ac (wave-2) routers can use the VHT160 channel modes. So we are basically waiting for everyone to catch up to the standards / buy new routers. The saving grace just may be that the 5.8Ghz band doesn't do to well as far as distance and object penetration, so even in a horrible rf environment you should still get usable speeds.

Comment: This answer is way better then mine. I think this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @davidgo, not a big deal. I added that as a compliment to your answer, not meant to be competition to it. I figured showing the available channels vs channel width would add context to your factually correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

The 5 gig band has A LOT  more capacity on it (exactly how much depends on country) , so it will support a lot more clients.

Additionally its range is much shorter with much less penetration through walls so there will be less interference from other transmitters, which means a lot more channel reuse.

Yes, if you have lots of users things could slow down, but on a properly designed network it will still vastly outperform 2.4 gig in terms of performance (but not as good at range, so more APs need to be deployed to cover a given large area)